# Add a comment to a cell of a Listobject in Excel Listobject table

Tags: excel, vba, listobject

I have a table (listobject) in excel where I want to add comments in some cells.

```
Dim infotbl As listobject
Set infotbl = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("index").ListObjects("infotbl")
Dim myString As String
myString = "Whatever"

' this line of code works:
infotbl.ListColumns(2).DataBodyRange.item(1).Interior.color = vbGreen

' one of the next two lines of code does not work:
infotbl.ListColumns(2).DataBodyRange.item(1).AddComment
infotbl.ListColumns(2).DataBodyRange.item(1).Comment.Text Text:=myString
```

The error is run error 1004
application defined or object-defined error.

I checked several posts in stackoverflow where I got the .AddComment and the .comment.Text methods, but they would not work.

some help?

thanks

Comment: `iTem` - is that how your word actually looks in the VBE? The capitalisation is off. The code works for me. Do you have a variable with the same name?

Comment: Is there already a comment there?

Comment: I agree with @SJR. A variable or a procedure or a module/class etc with the same name I guess?

Comment: I dont know why VBE makes iTem instead of Item. I searched for "Dim ITem" and there is not such variable. But in any case being enough strange that is not the problem becuase .iTem(1).Interior.color = vbGreen works and all other times I use .item its not a problem.

Comment: thanks for spotting. I will edit the question

Comment: and the follwoing works as well: infotbl.ListColumns(2).DataBodyRange.iTem(1).value = "XXX"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code works for me:

```
Sub TestTableComment()
    Dim infotbl As ListObject: Set infotbl = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("index").ListObjects("infotbl")
    Dim myString As String: myString = "Whatever"

    With infotbl.ListColumns(2).DataBodyRange
        .Item(1).Interior.Color = vbGreen
        .Item(1).ClearComments
        .Item(1).AddComment myString
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: That was it. apparently .addcomment myString DOES NOT OVERRIDE the comment if there is any. So first delete it, then add it again. thanks.